# Overriding onBackPressed in other Classes

Tags: android

in my app, i used a lot of Override onBackPressed.
my mean is this:in the method onBackPressed is very line of codes in my app, and i want this codes From MainActivity  goed to Another class.how i can?Because the MainActivity is very crowded and tangled.
{I'm persian and my english languige is bad! i'm sorry if you Do not understand my mean.}
Maybe it's better to ask this
I want to write the code in another place and call it in the onBackPressed..., but it does not answer///Tell me the way I am an amateur

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Вы не можете выйти",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
TextView TextView0;
TextView TextView1;
TextView TextView2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView0=findViewById(R.id.textView0);
    TextView1=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView2=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String smstext = "не-можете выйти";

    String[] man = smstext.split("\\-{1}|\\s+");
    String sag =man[2]+man[3];

    TextView0.append(man[0]);
    TextView1.append(man[1]);
    TextView2.setText(sag);

}
}
```

how to method onBackPressed go to other class like this:

```
public class back extends MainActivity {

}
```

Comment: I now give you my code

Comment: This is not a use case of code reusing. You can not use same code  on each Activity`s `onBackPressed()`. Jut keep it that way. You can  other common code in a Utility class for re-usability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, for example, show a `Toast` every time user presses a back button and on every screen, you have two options:

1. Implement `onBackPressed` method in every activity and call some utility class to do that, for example `Toasts.showMessage()`.
2. You can inherit every activity from your `BaseActivity` where you can override `onBackPressed` method and show toast there.